# i try to run the program but it doesn't display in a table form. how do i fix this? below are part of my configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table id = "datatable">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datatable").dataTable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial">
<table id="datatable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

> $(document).ready(function() {
>       $("#datatable").dataTable();
>       });

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Start at https://validator.w3.org/nu/ and worry about why it doesn't work after you've removed the machine detectable errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `thead` and `tbody`. Check your HTML so it looks like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#example").dataTable();
})
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>line1</td>
            <td>line2</td>
            <td>line3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/bvxekcxy/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @annoyingmouse i got it already. thanks for the answer and the link above. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small change on my code and finally I got it in a `data table`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datatable").dataTable()
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="datatable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```